# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider in Oracle

Tags: odp.net

string constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=spp01)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=Global)));User

Id=SYSMAN;Password=testman3";
            string ProviderName = "Oracle.DataAccess.Client";

```
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);
```

I am able to connect to oracle in console and winforms application. The code above is in a seperate class library. I have installed 64bit ODAC.

The ORACLE.DATAACCESS is set to 2.x ver 2.112.3.0. I have checked machine.config entries Framework64 v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319

type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

CPU = Any CPU Framework=3.5

When I call the same code from class library in ASP.net then I get the following error

[image]
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)

I have even set the apppool to allow 32-bit applications.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 8):

The error shows that the Oracle client is not installed on your system. To validate it you can run the line of code below:

**System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses()**

You will get a DataTable of all the installed data providers. If Oracle.DataAccess.Client invarient is not listed in the DataTable then it means it is not installed.

I was also facing the same issue on one of our clients machine and on debugging i found that the Oracle client was installed from the Admin user and they were trying to access it from some other user.

**On installing the Oracle client from current user resolves the problem.**

Please don't forget to restart your application after installing the Oracle client.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need the data provider. I had the same problem with Oracle 11g when deploying to a Windows Server 2008 R2 and after installing their data provider on the server it worked. Didn't work on the first shot though I had to restart the web app a few times.

To check if you have the ODAC on the server simply dump this string to a log somewhere or anywhere you can see it:

```
private String GetDbProviders()
{
    // Retrieve the installed providers and factories.
    DataTable table = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

    StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();

    // Display each row and column value.
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            bob.AppendLine(" "+row[column]+" ");
        }
    }

    return bob.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hm, so when you develop a C# application in Visual Studio using ODAC, you also need to install ODAC on the server using the developed software??

Comment: I had this experience yes. I updated my answer so that you can use a function to find out if you have the Oracle ODAC.

Comment: I'm getting below but the application is still failing.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the common issues that all .NET developer who ever using the Oracle Client as Database will face.

#### Points to remember:

- Make sure you have installed Oracle ODAC from Oracle.
- Check if Oracle.DataAccess is properly installed:(Oracle.DataAccess should be there in DbProviderFactories section)

  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
- If oracle 32bit is installed make sure you're building an application in 32x.
- Even if you have 32bit/64bit system and 32bit/64bit application. You should refer the same Oracle.Database DLL version as on DbProviderFactories in machine.config

#### Screenshot for reference

[image: OracleDatabase in machine.config]

#### Quick Links:

- Download Path - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
- Similar answer - [ODP.NET Managed - Unable to find requested .Net Framework Data Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389319/odp-net-managed-unable-to-find-requested-net-framework-data-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the 64bit ODAC and install the 32 bit ODAC.