# Dbfactories.getfactory method is not able to establish connection when deployed on the server .net

Tags: c#, teradata, odp.net, dbproviderfactories

`Dbprovider.getfactory` is not establishing the connection when deployed on the servers.

```
dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Teradata.Client.Provider");
```

There are no errors in logs as well, it just crashes the application saying:

> Page cannot be displayed

Comment: This answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389319/odp-net-managed-unable-to-find-requested-net-framework-data-provider/25414885#25414885

Comment: Mostly this is assembly probing issue, the binary that you are loading or trying to load is not found and /or its not able to initialize the Factory class. Try using the `Teradata.Client.Provider` apis directly. While you create Factory you are trying to fill concrete class in the base abstract class and work using it, but direct usage will at least ensure that its working. Also general probing mechanism for signed assembly is GAC followed the project bin folder