# The ADO.NET provider 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded

Tags: c#, oracle, configuration, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

I am using `.NET4.5.1`, `MVC5`, `EF6`, with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.1.0` and
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.2.0`

I was able to generate Model from existing database (part of it adding table by table), application builds just fine.

However when I try run test query to see if it can get the data

```
 public ActionResult Cancellations()
    {
        var factoryClasses = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var cancelationStatuses = new[] {3, 7, 9};
           var result = db.TRANSACTIONDETAIL.Where(o => cancelationStatuses.Contains(o.TRANSACTIONSTATUSID));
           return View(result);
        }
    }
```

it fails (on `var result = ...`) with `Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

[When trying to look for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452328/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-in-oracle#answer-20606765) `DbProviderFactories` indeed there is nothing in collection (`var factoryClasses =`).

However [I do have installed 12c 4 (ODTwithODAC121024)](http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html) and 11g (ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit), and have restarted machine.

Database is running on 11g and I can access it with `PL/SQL developer` 
[image]

Web.config looks following:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
.....
<connectionStrings>
.....
<add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password;Data Source=oracle" />
 <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OracleDb.csdl|res://*/OracleDb.ssdl|res://*/OracleDb.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string='data source=******" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />           </connectionStrings>
......
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <!-- Remove in case this is already defined in machine.config -->
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

My assumption it's failing because Oracle is not being registered in `DbProviderFactories` or somewhere

**How do I register Oracle in DbProviderFactories? Or if this is not the case what is wrong with my setup?**

Comment: Did you download and include the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` library?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes it's in nuget references version 4.121.1.0

Comment: `Oracle + MS = hell` I still can't figure wtf is wrong

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered this error when i updated Visual Studio 2017.
The error can be resolved by reinstalling ODT for VS 2017:

1) Close Visual Studio.

2) Uninstall the existing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 from control Panel.

3) Install the latest one (ODTforVS2017_122011.exe) from the following link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html

4) Open visual studio and build solution.The error should not generate now.

Comment: This was solution for me. Thank you dude!

Comment: This was the fix for me as well, ODTforVS2017 version 18.3.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533943/the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-oracle-dataaccess-client-not-register

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.

In my `machine.config` there was already

```
<add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

and then it was repeated in my `web.config` which would silently fail to give out any providers. So after taking out:

```
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

I got it running.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by adding ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12c) from NuGet. I'm running VS2015 with EF 6.2.0.

Comment: I tried it firstly because of this looks quicker then removing "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017" answer but it doesn't worked for me, then I removed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 and reinstalled, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved this error by installing Oracle Developer tool for visual studio 2013 (my installed VS version)
ODTforVS2013_121025.exe