# Entity Framework to access Oracle db

Tags: iis, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

In one of my project, I'm using Entity Framework to access data in an Oracle database. It works fine when running from VS and also on my local IIS. But when I deploy it to the QA box, I get this error:

> Failed to retrieve WhShipmentEntity.System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

I'm new to Entity Framework. Is that error means that I need to install the Oracle ODP for .NET on that QA box? I was thinking all necessary dll will be packaged into the bin directory when I publish to the IIS.

Comment: Examine the settings in your web.config and the machine.config. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271009/the-ado-net-provider-oracle-manageddataaccess-client-is-either-not-registered

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Oracle ODP for .NET on the dev server and it is working now.  I was under the assumption that this is only needed when development software in VS, and VS will put all the necessary Oracle dll in bin during publishing process.  I guess that is not the case.