# 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.Oracle' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: oracle, odata, devart

Ok, there already is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271009/the-ado-net-provider-oracle-manageddataaccess-client-is-either-not-registered). It is, however not exactly the same and the solution I got was not derived from the other issue's solution.

Here's my Web.Config setup:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADOEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ADOModel.csdl|res://*/ADOModel.ssdl|res://*/ADOModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=dbUser;Password=*****;Server=oracleserver;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Everything runs fine *on my machine (sic)*, but when I tried to set the ws up on the quality server, I got the error on the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by following the steps in this [ADO.NET](https://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html#ProviderRegistration) link. Particularly,

> You need to remove the defaultConnectionFactory registration and to add the Entity Framework provider registration by registering it in the entityFramework section

So the line *defaultConnectionFactory* must go

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EF6, Version=9.6.696.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Then, add the *System.Data* section. In my case it looks like this:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Devart.Data.Oracle" />
      <add name="dotConnect for Oracle" invariant="Devart.Data.Oracle" description="Devart dotConnect for Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleProviderFactory, Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=9.6.696.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

If that still doesn't do the trick for you -- And it didn't for me -- try adding the following line to your context class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServicesConfiguration))] //Add this line
public partial class ADOEntities : DbContext
```

You might want to create a partial class, incase you're using ADO, Devart, or other auto-generated entity model, to avoid having this piece of code in an auto-generated class